# Make partition from installed Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have an Ubuntu installed on my workstation with 500 Gb HD, I didn't keep any partition for installing a dual-boot. I want to play around elementary OS.
Is there a possibility of freeing a partition for dual-boot without discarding my current installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the other question, as the user has already had more than one partition unlike my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How *exactly* do the solutions posted to that question, for example [the top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/480481), not work in your case? Number of partitions seems to be a pretty insignificant detail here, the main issue is **resizing a partition to free up some space** which I believe is addressed adequately there.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Live USB version of Ubuntu before you boot into the Elementry OS installer since I'm not sure if the disk tools needed are present in that distro. Once booted choose "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install" to enter the "Live" mode and run either `gnome-disks` or `gparted` and resize your existing partition creating free space then when installing Elementry OS they should give you an option to use existing free space on the disk.